# Print jobs automatically deleted at the printer

Tags: windows-10, printer, network-printer

I have one Windows 10 PC which is exhibiting a peculiar phenomenon.

It is a Samsung CLX9xxx printer on the network. The driver appears to install fine. I can send a test page or a print job. The print queue shows the job sent and printed at the printer. However, at the printer, the Job Status screen (it has one of these as it is a big multi-function printer/copier) shows the job as Deleted, and nothing gets printed.

What could be causing this problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try to check or reset printer parameters.

Comment: Printer parameters? At the printer?

Comment: Yes, at the printer.

Comment: @harrymc it's not the printer itself. *Only one* computer is described as being unable to print to this printer, so the logical place to start is at the "one Windows 10 PC" with the problem, not altering settings at the printer itself, which would only risk introducing complications that could potentially affect other users. Other Windows 10 computers are printing to this printer with no issues. The printer is fine. OP: focus on removing the print driver and installing it again, then trying different versions of the driver.

Comment: Does it work for other computers? If so, is the computer different from the others?

Comment: It's working for other computers. Windows 10 is so complex that it is difficult to determine how this PC is different from the others.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when the wrong print driver is installed on the client computer that is sending that print job.